# Importing Google's Zip Expansion library

Tags: android

I am trying to utilize the `Zip Expansion library` from Google in my app, but I cannot seem to import the libraries correctly.

Right now, in my code, to test the library, I am using :

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile();
```

This is throwing errors because I have not imported the expansion library correctly.

From scratch, could someone tell me how to use this library in my project?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you import it with: `import com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile;`?  What error are you getting?

Comment: It cannot resolve "com.android.vending"
I thought I would just type out the command and hover over and it would suggest : "Import .... "

Comment: ? 
I have the android market app installed on my device... but I'm pretty sure the code does not care what I have on my device..

Comment: Have you added a reference to the library at `<sdk>/extras/google/google_market_apk_expansion/zip_file/`?

Comment: I right clicked my project and imported it.. but I'm positive I did it wrong. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, import the 'zip_file' project (using 'copy projects into workspace' option).  Add a reference to this project under your project properties, then add the project to your Java Build Path.  Add the namespace to your code file:

```
import src.com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.*;
```

Using `ZipResourceFile` should not throw any errors at this point.  You should also mark this dependency as an Android library under your project properties so that it will be managed properly when building.

Comment: How can we achieve this in Android Studio?